# Need help on Hive query

Tags: hive

```
hive> describe hivecustomers;
OK
cust_id                 int                                         
cust_fname              string                                      
cust_lname              string                                      
cust_email              string                                      
cust_password           string                                      
cust_street             string                                      
cust_city               string                                      
cust_state              string                                      
cust_zipcode            string   

hive> describe hiveorders;
OK
ord_id                  int                                         
ord_dt                  string                                      
ord_cust_id             int                                         
ord_stat                string      


hive> select * from hiveorders limit 3; 

OK 
1 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 11599 CLOSED 
2 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 256 PENDING_PAYMENT 
3 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 12111 COMPLETE 


hive> select * from hivecustomers limit 3; 
OK 
1 Richard Hernandez XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 6303 Heather Plaza Brownsville TX 78521 
2 Mary Barrett XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 9526 Noble Embers Ridge Littleton CO 80126 
3 Ann Smith XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 3422 Blue Pioneer Bend Caguas PR 00725
```

Based on the above two tables, I need output as following in Hive, how can I write query to this job ?

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-----+ 
|Cust Name  | Cust Address  | Total Orders  | Order Status |Count|      
+-----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-----+ 
|Andrew     |London         |15             |Complete      |8    |  
|Andrew     |London         |15             |Pending       |3    | 
|Andrew     |London         |15             |Processing    |4    | 
|Andrew     |London         |15             |On-Hold       |1    |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: hive> select * from hiveorders limit 3;
OK
1 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 11599 CLOSED
2 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 256 PENDING_PAYMENT
3 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 12111 COMPLETE
Time taken: 0.094 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> select * from hivecustomers limit 3;
OK
1 Richard Hernandez XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 6303 Heather Plaza Brownsville TX 78521
2 Mary Barrett XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 9526 Noble Embers Ridge Littleton CO 80126
3 Ann Smith XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 3422 Blue Pioneer Bend Caguas PR 00725
Time taken: 0.1 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used your data as a CTE (common table expressions) and tested it. Cuctomer 1 has two PENDING_PAYMENT orders and 4 in total, all others have one order per status and 3 each in total:

```
with hivecustomers  as
(
select 1 as cust_id , 'Richard'  as cust_fname union all
select 2 as cust_id , 'Mary'     as cust_fname union all
select 3 as cust_id , 'Ann'      as cust_fname
),
hiveorders as
(
select 1 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 1 as ord_cust_id, 'CLOSED'          as ord_stat union all
select 2 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 1 as ord_cust_id, 'PENDING_PAYMENT' as ord_stat union all
select 3 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 1 as ord_cust_id, 'COMPLETE'        as ord_stat union all
select 4 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 1 as ord_cust_id, 'PENDING_PAYMENT'        as ord_stat union all
select 21 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 2 as ord_cust_id, 'CLOSED'          as ord_stat union all
select 22 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 2 as ord_cust_id, 'PENDING_PAYMENT' as ord_stat union all
select 23 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 2 as ord_cust_id, 'COMPLETE'        as ord_stat union all
select 31 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 3 as ord_cust_id, 'CLOSED'          as ord_stat union all
select 32 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 3 as ord_cust_id, 'PENDING_PAYMENT' as ord_stat union all
select 33 as ord_id, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0' as ord_dt, 3 as ord_cust_id, 'COMPLETE'        as ord_stat
) 
select cust_fname, total_orders, order_status, count(*) Count 
from
(
select c.cust_fname, 
       count(*) over(partition by c.cust_id) as total_orders,
       o.ord_stat as Order_Status
  from hivecustomers c left join hiveorders o on c.cust_id=o.ord_cust_id
 )s
  group by cust_fname, total_orders, order_status
```

Output:

```
OK
cust_fname      total_orders    order_status    count
Ann     3       CLOSED  1
Ann     3       COMPLETE        1
Ann     3       PENDING_PAYMENT 1
Mary    3       CLOSED  1
Mary    3       COMPLETE        1
Mary    3       PENDING_PAYMENT 1
Richard 4       CLOSED  1
Richard 4       COMPLETE        1
Richard 4       PENDING_PAYMENT 2
Time taken: 40.692 seconds, Fetched: 9 row(s)
```

Just remove CTE and use normal tables instead.

Comment: Awesome ! Just that I meant "Total Customer Orders" NOT "Total  Orders".

Comment: I get the following output using Hive query : hive> select  count(*), count(*) over (partition by ord_cust_id), ord_cust_id, ord_stat from hiveorders group by ord_cust_id, ord_stat;

1 4 12432 ON_HOLD
1 4 12432 PENDING
2 4 12432 PENDING_PAYMENT
6 4 12432 COMPLETE
1 5 12434 CLOSED
3 5 12434 COMPLETE
1 5 12434 ON_HOLD
2 5 12434 PENDING
1 5 12434 PENDING_PAYMENT
1 2 12435 PENDING
1 2 12435 CANCELED
Time taken: 107.767 seconds, Fetched: 43460 row(s)

If you see the SECOND column carefully, I get the output 4, 5, 2 WHEREAS I should get the output as 10, 8, 2

Can you help ?

Comment: hive> select * from hiveorders limit 3; 

OK 
1 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 11599 CLOSED 
2 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 256 PENDING_PAYMENT 
3 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0 12111 COMPLETE 


hive> select * from hivecustomers limit 3; 
OK 
1 Richard Hernandez XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 6303 Heather Plaza Brownsville TX 78521 
2 Mary Barrett XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 9526 Noble Embers Ridge Littleton CO 80126 
3 Ann Smith XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX 3422 Blue Pioneer Bend Caguas PR 00725

Comment: @GurpreetSingh If it works and you are satisfied w my work, then please accept or vote